# Google Play - Pub Sub - RTDN messages are not sent to Topic when using Test licences

Tags: android, google-play, google-cloud-pubsub, rtdn

We correctly configured google play, Pub Sub and our backend so test notifications are correctly sent from google play console, received in PubSub Topic and then consumed correctly by our backend.
But when we purchase an item in mobile app using test account, we can see in google play console that the command is successfull, but no message is published in Topic and  backend doesn't receive any notification (RTDN).
Any one faced the same issue? how can we test the overall purchase flow before releasing our app?

Many thanks for your help
Best regards